# Fill the area with texture cocos2d-x

Tags: arrays, opengl, textures, cocos2d-x, texture2d

I've been trying to make "Obstacle" class which builds box2d body by array of points and draw the area which my body covers. As for body, it works totally ok, I receive array of points, build b2PolygonShape and so on. BUT, I really don't know, how to fill the area with color or texture which was built by points array. Here's my draw() method:

```
void Obstacle::draw(cocos2d::Renderer *renderer, const cocos2d::Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags)
```

{
    CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP();

```
glBlendFunc(CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST);
GL::bindTexture2D(obstacleTexture->getName());
//DrawPrimitives::setDrawColor4F(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)shapePoints.size());
```

}

vertices is the array of points which I use for creating b2body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should triangulate the polygon shape you built in order to draw.

poly2tri is a good option for triangulating shapes: https://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/

After triangulating your shape, map texture coordinates or set the vertex colors.